# Can I export a PDF from Inkscape with a vectorized blur or shadow?

Tags: inkscape, svg, pdf, blur

In Inkscape, I can draw a circle and add a blur.  If I save that document as a PDF, the blur is only kept if I rasterize it.  I'd like the PDF to keep the blur without rasterizing it.  Same goes for a drop shadow.

Is this a limitation of PDF?  If not, is there another tool to convert an SVG to a PDF with a blur or shadow?

If it matters, I'm using a Mac, but have Linux and Windows machines available.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There's no need to rasterize a blur or drop shadow in Inkscape before exporting a PDF.  Rasterizing will take place automatically when you export the PDF.  Make sure to save your SVG file if you want to keep it all as vector, for future editing. The SVG should be considered your source file.

Comment: Thanks, Billy. I do use SVG as my master/source file. I said "I'd like the PDF to keep the blur without rasterizing it". I'm not asking about how to rasterize it.

Comment: Sorry, for the misunderstanding. But there's no way for a PDF to have a vector that is blurred. In Inkscape that is achieved using an SVG blur effect. For a PDF it has to be rendered as as a raster image.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a "vector blur". It does not exist.

It's not a limitation of PDFs or any operating system. The nature of vector content simply precludes the creation of soft edges with the exception of gradients. And blurs, or canned drop shadows, are never automatically converted to gradients anywhere I've ever seen.

Applications ***preview*** the raster based blur using existing vector objects a the basis. No blur or canned drop shadow effect is ever going to be vector upon output.

If you need strictly vector content, then using gradients is the better option. In many instances you can create a gradient to mimic a blur or drop shadow. Gradients **will** remain vector when output in most instances.

Comment: I don't understand.  How can you say vector blur doesn't exist when the spec for Scalable *Vector* Graphics includes blurring, drop shadows, etc.?
https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/#feGaussianBlurElement
The SVG file has a shadow.  I want to know how to put that shadow into another vector format.

Comment: The blurring in SVG is done via filters is still a raster blur,. It is merely constructed internally "on-the-fly" the same way applications like Inkscape or Illustrator create their raster-based blurs. It's nto a "vector blur" though.

Comment: Okay. Whether you call it a raster blur or a vector blur, I want the PDF to do the thing that the SVG is doing.

Comment: It can't. PDFs don't work like that.

Answer (score -1):

Vector blur exists in Affinity Designer, not a myth. This is a hybrid feature that can create soft masking.

Comment: Its not really a blur, its more of a swept gradient mesh. It can look like a blur in many cases but its not resally a blur as it does not have same distribution. Illustrator can also do this its just not called a blur. But please dont use answer fields for comments.

Comment: I have answered the question, vector blur is a feature in Affinity Designer, it also exist in Blender3D composite masking that can even define the blur radius by individual vertice.

Comment: But you are not answering about inkscape nor PDF and svg compatibility. Blender does not generate PDF or svg compatible vectors. (Yes technically all 3D effects are vector drawings but dont get considered ones)

Answer (score -2):

It can be done with gradient meshes but there is no tutorial I could find and I can't quite remember how I did this (sorry ) but hope one can pick up the basic idea from this. To replicate the look of a drop shadow with gradient meshes. When scaled down or printed it looks fine, and even when zoomed in, at least it's not pixelated

[image: switch with gradient mesh shadow]

[image]

[Edit: please give comments about downvotes, why isn't this a legit workaround to the original issue?]